# Handling 'onkeydown' event

Tags: javascript, events, audio, event-handling, onkeydown

I've added `onkeydown` event listener to `document`, and when the event fires, I play an audio file. This audio file is a gun sound. If you tap the key once, it plays fine, but if you press and hold, the audio repeats incredibly fast. I've solved that with a simple `playing` condition check, but I have another problem. If I press and hold, only after the first shot, it sounds like the gun is firing repeatedly. For example, it goes like *ta-tatatatata*.

How can I fix my machine gun? Make it fire like *tatatata*.

[**Demo**](http://akinuri.com/exps/css-launchpad/test.html)

---

```
var weapons = {
    aug : {
        audio   : "weapons/aug-1.wav",
        icon    : "e",
        key     : "A"
    }
};

function playAudio(file) {
    if (!playing) {
        var audio = new Audio(file);
        audio.play();
        playing = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            playing = false;
        }, 100);
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            playAudio(weapons.aug.audio);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to code this before thinking about it, and that was my first mistake. I've solved the problem now. All I had to do was simply mimic the FPS games' fire command. Start an interval with the `mousedown` and clear the interval with `mouseup`.

Instead of using mouse click, I had to use key press. So when I press a key (and hold), an interval starts and plays the audio repeatedly. When I release the key, interval is cleared, audio stops.

[Demo](http://akinuri.com/exps/css-launchpad/test.html)

```
var weapons = {
    aug : {
        audio       : "weapons/aug-1.wav",
        icon        : "e",
        key         : "A",
        interval    : null,
        firstShot   : false,
    }
};

function playAudio(file, weapon) {
    if (!weapon.interval) {
        if (!weapon.firstShot) {
            var audio = new Audio(file);
            audio.play();
            weapons.aug.firstShot = true;
        }
        weapon.interval = setInterval(function() {
            var audio = new Audio(file);
            audio.play();
        }, 150);
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            playAudio(weapons.aug.audio, weapons.aug);
            break;
    }
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            clearInterval(weapons.aug.interval);
            weapons.aug.interval = null;
            weapons.aug.firstShot = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

akinuri, this was my first answer, but I deleted it (I thought you wanted to play the whole sound), so I undeleted it, it could help you (it will fix the delay bug of keydown).

You should use a gameLoop (common pattern in game development), with `requestAnimationFrame`.
Don't trigger events directly from player's input, set states that will be processed inside the gameLoop (which should be in charge of updating positions, rendering ...)

```
var playing = false;

var keyStatePressed = false;//set state at false at init

var weapons = {
    aug : {
        audio   : "weapons/aug-1.wav",
        icon    : "e",
        key     : "A"
    }
};

function playAudio(file) {
    if (!playing) {
        var audio = new Audio(file);
        audio.play();
        playing = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            playing = false;
        }, 100);
    }
}

//flag at true on keydown
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            keyStatePressed = true;
            break;
    }
}

//run a game loop
function gameLoop(){
    if(keyStatePressed === true){
        playAudio(weapons.aug.audio);
        keyStatePressed = false;//reset state
    }
    //run this in 16ms (see more on game loops and requestAnimationFrame)
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

//launch the gameLoop
gameLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

There should probably be a better way with a gameLoop and less globals, but wait for the `ended` event of the audio object to tag `playing` at `false` and be sure not to start playing your sound unless it's finished.

```
var playing = false;//tag playing as false by default

var weapons = {
    aug : {
        audio   : "weapons/aug-1.wav",
        icon    : "e",
        key     : "A"
    }
};

function playAudio(file) {
    if (!playing) {
        audio = new Audio(file);
        playing = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            playing = false;
        },400);
        audio.play();
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            playAudio(weapons.aug.audio);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `playAudio` function, there is an undefined variable `audio`. The one you added the `ended` event listener. I'm re-creating the  `audio` object each play because it needs to sound like a gun fire. If I play the sound when the previous play ends, it won't sound right. There'll be pause between the shots. The audio file is 1~ second long, but the actual shot sound is much shorter, somewhere around 400ms. So I need to interrupt and fire again before the previous play ends.

Comment: my bad - forgot to update the end of your method after copy/paste `audio` becomes `audios[file]`

Comment: You can see what I'm talking about in [here](http://akinuri.com/exps/css-launchpad/index2.html), the pause between the shots. I need to create the audio object each play.

Comment: Changed the code in case you don't want to wait until the end of the whole file to play

Comment: Tested the last version. Doesn't work. Setting the timeout to 400ms wouldn't work, because the audio object still refers to the same object. You can't play the same audio again while it's already playing. The boolen `playing` doesn't help here. That's why I was re-creating it each play. [**same link, updated**](http://akinuri.com/exps/css-launchpad/index2.html)

Comment: You're right about limitations on playing multiple times the audio object, I changed the code but it seems to be the same as yours, am I missing something ?

Comment: Nothing to do with audio : it's the `keydown`, it triggers a first event, a second one 500ms later and the one after that, at rate of 33ms ... this is why you have "ta-tatatatata"

Comment: Check out my other answer for more ideas ;)

Comment: I'll definitely look into the gameLoop thing. I'm thinking about coding a game, so it'll be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hey let me know if it works I hope it helps !

```
var weapons = {
    aug : {
        audio   : "weapons/aug-1.wav",
        icon    : "e",
        key     : "A"
    }
};
function loadAudio(file) {
    var audio = new Audio(file);
    return audio;
}

function playAudio(file) {
        audio.play();
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            var gunsound = loadAudio(weapons.aug.audio);
            playAudio(gunsound);
            setTimeout(function() {},200);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this code doesn't solve the problem. It just takes me back to where I started. The audio plays without any delay between the shots. [Demo](http://akinuri.com/exps/css-launchpad/index3.html)